# Can't open mp3 file with audiotools in python

Tags: python, audio, mp3

I have this problem with opening every mp3 files:

```
import os
import audiotools

t=os.listdir('/home/jedrzej/Desktop/muz')
t[10]

'12 - High Road (Feat. John Legend).mp3'

stream=audiotools.open(t[10])

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/audiotools/__init__.py", line 1445, in open
  raise UnsupportedFile(filename)

audiotools.UnsupportedFile: 12 - High Road (Feat. John Legend).mp3
```

it's working with wav files.
please help!

Edit: I had not installed lame, now after installation everything works.

Answer (score 0):

It might be because the file you want to open contains spaces. Try with a file name that has no spaces.

Comment: thanks for answer! The problem was my stupidity, I have not installed lame.